# One dynamic EntityManager, connecting to several databases, being transaction-type = "JTA​​"

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipselink, ejb-3.0, entitymanager, jpa-2.1

I have several databases with the same structure allocated on different servers (one database for each of my customers), my application needs to connect to all of them dynamically 
using JTA. So when a customer X perform some database operation, the application must decide at runtime in which database it shoud connect, and this operation shoud be performed only on this specific database.And there is another problem, I will have to create one connection pool for each of my customers, if one of them fails to connect, glassfish won't even start.

I have looked and everywhere and I coundn't find a good solution. Could anyone help me? I'm using EJB 3 and JPA2 with EclipseLink.

It could work if I change the unitName's value of the PersistenceContext annotation at runtime, does anyone know if it's possible to do that?

Comment: You need to flesh out what you want from your application a bit more.  Similar database structure, does that mean you will use the same Java entity model?  When you try to search for an entity, which database(s) will JPA look in?  How do you expect to control which databases are written to?  The simplest solution is to create multiple persistence units, each one having its own datasource to its own database.  You would then tie the xa datasources to JTA in your server.

Comment: Question rewrited. @Chris

Comment: I'm not sure why Glassfish wont start if your datasource can't connect.  There are many ways to create a datasource in glassfish, and I assume Glassfish can be started independently of its datasources.  Are you referring to the application not working when the datasource isn't available when using a container managed Persistence unit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to load multiple database instances in one single `EntityManager`. What should it do if you want to insert an entity? Insert it in all of them? What happens if you find two different users but with the same id in two distinct databases?

What you can do is load n default EntityManagers for each database instance and then implement your own EntityManager which should delegate work to the default ones.

If you are using Java EE 6+, you can use CDI to inject your custom built EntityManager; just make it an EJB (annotating it with `@Stateless`) and then inject it where you want annotating the field with `@Inject`:

Comment: @lucianovcnt rewrite/rewrote/rewritten

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a multitenant application where each tenant has its own database.  I believe you are better of designing it so that each tenant has its own persistenceUnit as described here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant

Injection though is not available if you go this route because you will need to control properties used to create PersistenceUnits for each tenant.  It does allow you to use one persistence.xml file - you would then either pass in the datasource to use for that tenant via http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.5/org/eclipse/persistence/config/EntityManagerProperties.html#JTA_DATASOURCE or use a customizer to figure it out based on the tenant.  Resources for the tenant only need to exist when the EntityManager/EntityManagerFactory is first used, not at startup, so you can dynamically add tenants as long as you can configure and add datasources for them.